# Show locale date on an iphone using php

Tags: php, date, locale, web

The problem is that my php code uses date function to show the date,and like any other browser it shows the locale date. Its working for an android phone as well but i dont think its working on iphone. this is just a normal php file and it opens in a web browser. How do i show the current locale time according to the browser of an iphone using php?

Answer (score 0):

As far I know php cant get locale date of the client, because it runs on server, what you can do its to show the locale client via javascript.

Then can you retrive the locale date via javascript to php via ajax or something similar.

How it works on android? If you can show that part of your code maybe we can provide a more accurate answer